# How to compare elements in a list of lists and compare keys in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

I have the following sequence:

```
seq = [['ATG','ATG','ATG','ATG'],['GAC','GAT','GAA','CCT'],['GCC','GCG','GCA','GCT']]
```

Here is a dictionary key that stores the value of amino acid for each of the codons (Triplet bases like `ATG, GCT` etc).

```
aminoacid = {'TTT' : 'F','TTC' : 'F','TTA' : 'L','TTG' : 'L','CTT' : 'L','CTC' : 'L','CTA' : 'L','CTG' : 'L','ATT' : 'I','ATC' : 'I','ATA' : 'I','ATG' : 'M','GTT' : 'V','GTC' : 'V','GTA' : 'V','GTG' : 'V','TCT' : 'S','TCC' : 'S','TCA' : 'S','TCG' : 'S','CCT' : 'P','CCC' : 'P','CCA' : 'P','CCG' : 'P','ACT' : 'T','ACC' : 'T','ACA' : 'T','ACG' : 'T','GCT' : 'A','GCC' : 'A','GCA' : 'A','GCG' : 'A','TAT' : 'Y','TAC' : 'Y','TAA' : 'STOP','TAG' : 'STOP','CAT' : 'H','CAC' : 'H','CAA' : 'Q','CAG' : 'Q','AAT' : 'N','AAC' : 'N','AAA' : 'K','AAG' : 'K','GAT' : 'D','GAC' : 'D','GAA' : 'E','GAG' : 'E','TGT' : 'C','TGC' : 'C','TGA' : 'STOP','TGG' : 'W','CGT' : 'R','CGC' : 'R','CGA' : 'R','CGG' : 'R','AGT' : 'S','AGC' : 'S','AGA' : 'R','AGC' : 'R','GGT' : 'G','GGC' : 'G','GGA' : 'G','GGG' : 'G'}
```

As one can see several codons can code for the same aminoacid (eg. `GGT,GGC,GGA, GGG etc all code for Glycine (G)` ). These are Synonymous (PSyn) and if codons code for different amino acids they are Non-Synonymous (PNonsyn)

In this code, I need to do the following:

1. For each element in the list of lists, if there is a change in the bases AND they all code for the same amino acid, then increase count of PSyn by 1 and if it codes for different amino acids increment count PNonsyn by 1

   Here,

   ```
   ATG all code for M #However, all are ATG's no change in bases. So no increment in count

   GAC, GAT for D; GAA for E; and CCT for P #Codes for three different amino acids, increment count by 1

   GGT,GGC,GGA, GGG for G #Different bases but all code for same amino acids, increment count by 1
   ```

   OutPut:
   `CountPsyn = 1`
   `CountPNonsyn = 1`
2. Generate a list of amino acids that corresponds to the above seq. such that:

   `Output : ['ATG','nonsyn','G'] #For sites with different aminoacids, the list should say nonsyn and for sites which had identical bases it should list the bases`

I need help modifying the following code to get the program to work. I am not confident on how to call values from dictionary and check them against all the elements. 
Code Attempted:

```
countPsyn = 0
countPnonsyn = 0
listofaa =[]

for i in seq:
    for base, value in enumerate(i):        
        if value[i] == value[i+1]: #eg. ['ATG','ATG','ATG','ATG'] 
            listofaa.append(value)

        if value[i] != value[i+1]: 
            if aminoacid[value][i] ==  aminoacid[value][i+1]: #eg.['GCC','GCG','GCA','GCT']
                countPsyn =+ 1
                listofaa.append(aminoacid)
            else: #eg. ['GAC','GAT','GAA','CCT']
                countPnonsyn =+ 1
                listofaa.append('nonsyn')

File Output can be found [here][1] https://eval.in/669107
```

Comment: please fix indentation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it

Comment: This is a hard one I'm not a bioengineer but I will try lol.

Comment: @thesonyman101 Thanks! I have already laid out an outline for the code. Perhaps along similar lines?

Comment: you don't have 'GCC' key in your `aminoacid` dictionary

Comment: @Tuan333 : Aghh! Thanks for pointing out the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my stab at the solution.

```
aminoacid = {'GCC': 'A' ,'TTT' : 'F','TTC' : 'F','TTA' : 'L','TTG' : 'L','CTT' : 'L','CTC' : 'L','CTA' : 'L','CTG' : 'L','ATT' : 'I','ATC' : 'I','ATA' : 'I','ATG' : 'M','GTT' : 'V','GTC' : 'V','GTA' : 'V','GTG' : 'V','TCT' : 'S','TCC' : 'S','TCA' : 'S','TCG' : 'S','CCT' : 'P','CCC' : 'P','CCA' : 'P','CCG' : 'P','ACT' : 'T','ACC' : 'T','ACA' : 'T','ACG' : 'T','GCT' : 'A','GCG' : 'A','GCA' : 'A','GCG' : 'A','TAT' : 'Y','TAC' : 'Y','TAA' : 'STOP','TAG' : 'STOP','CAT' : 'H','CAC' : 'H','CAA' : 'Q','CAG' : 'Q','AAT' : 'N','AAC' : 'N','AAA' : 'K','AAG' : 'K','GAT' : 'D','GAC' : 'D','GAA' : 'E','GAG' : 'E','TGT' : 'C','TGC' : 'C','TGA' : 'STOP','TGG' : 'W','CGT' : 'R','CGC' : 'R','CGA' : 'R','CGG' : 'R','AGT' : 'S','AGC' : 'S','AGA' : 'R','AGC' : 'R','CGT' : 'G','GGC' : 'G','GGA' : 'G','GGG' : 'G',}

seq = [['ATG','ATG','ATG','ATG'],['GAC','GAT','GAA','CCT'],['GCC','GCG','GCA','GCT']]

Psyn = 0;
PNonsyn = 0;
output = [];

#loop through each list in your list of list
for sublist in seq:
    acids = [aminoacid[base] for base in sublist]
    if len(set(acids)) != 1: #if there are different amino acids, then nonsync
        output.append('nonsync')
        PNonsyn += 1
    else: #if same amino acid
        if len(set(sublist)) == 1: #if same base
            output.append(sublist[0]);
        else: #if not same base
            output.append(acids[0]);
            Psyn += 1

print "Psyn = "+ str(Psyn)
print "PNonsyn = "+ str(PNonsyn)
print output
```

Admittedly it's not a modification of your code, but there is a neat trick here to void the double `for` loop. Given a list `mylist`, you could find all uniques elements in a list by calling `set(mylist)`. E.g.

```
>>> a = ['AGT','AGT','ACG']
>>> set(a)
set(['AGT', 'ACG'])
>>> len(set(a))
2
```